# WordPress Woocommerce plugin not setting orders to "processing"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the WooCommerce plug-in in WordPress. I'm selling downloadable items. I've got the product set to 'virtual' and 'downloadable' and the IPN is functioning fine as well as everything else, according to the System Status.

However, when I place an order, I have to manually set it to 'Processed' in order for it to send the download and confirmation email to the user. Is there any way to make that automatic? I don't want my client to have to manually process every order.

Thanks!

Comment: I've also tried installing WooCommerce Autocomplete Order plugin - http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-autocomplete-order/ - that hasn't worked either.

Comment: I found the issue. There was an htaccess password set on a directory and it was interfering with the PayPal IPN.